# Spreadsheet Functions converts dates into text

Tags: excel, coldfusion, spreadsheet, coldfusion-11

I am using spreadsheet functions for my Excel reports, but it converts dates into text when exported to Excel. So, I used datatype 'Date' in [SpreadSheetSetCellValue](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-s/spreadsheetsetcellvalue.html), so the values in the first column can be converted into any date format the customer wants. Here is the code:

```
 <cfset SpreadsheetSetCellValue(objSheet, '#RecordDate#', iRow, 1, 'Date')>
```

This works fine, but when I later apply a background color to alternate rows:

```
<cfset stFormat.AlternateRow = StructNew()>
<cfset stFormat.AlternateRow.fgcolor = 'yellow'>

<cfif (iRow mod 2) IS 0>
    <cfset SpreadsheetFormatRow(objSheet, stFormat.AlternateRow, iRow)>
</cfif>
```

It converts *all* of the columns in that row to 'date' format. Whereas I only want the 1st column, in each row, to be of 'date' datetype.

Comment: What's your CF version? Sounds like a bug to me. May need to apply formats individually.

Comment: We have CF11 version

Comment: I'd put together a standalone repro case and submit a bug https://bugbase.adobe.com . What happened when you tried formatting cells/columns individually - as a workaround?

Comment: I've not done it recently, and when I did it was with version 9, but I vaguely remember that attempting this sort of thing with large amounts of data was painfully slow.  With that in mind, you might have better luck formatting your row before adding data to it.

Comment: ya the problem is I need to create row/add data to it and then format - seems like a bug now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a bug to me.  I'd put together a repro case and submit a bug [bugbase.adobe.com](https://bugbase.adobe.com/).

Though not ideal, one possible workaround is to set the date column value *after* formatting the row. Unfortunately setting the cell value also wipes out the background color, so you need to reapply that as well. Tested with CF11, YMMV.

*NB: The workaround doesn't change the order of the columns at all, only **when they're formatted**. So the "date" still ends up in the 1st column.*

[Runnable Example on TryCF.com](https://trycf.com/gist/41947af0d59547de0142d0d932c27994/acf11?theme=monokai)

```
<cfscript>
    objSheet = SpreadSheetNew("Sheet1", true);
    for(iRow = 1; iRow <= 100; iRow++) {

        // populate everything EXCEPT the date column
        SpreadsheetSetCellValue(objSheet, "B", iRow, 2);
        SpreadsheetSetCellValue(objSheet, "C", iRow, 3);
        SpreadsheetSetCellValue(objSheet, "D", iRow, 4);
        SpreadsheetSetCellValue(objSheet, "1234", iRow, 5);

        isAlternateRow = (iRow MOD 2) EQ 0;
        rowColor = isAlternateRow ? 'yellow' : 'white';

        // format whole row 
        if (isAlternateRow) {
            SpreadsheetFormatRow(objSheet, { fgcolor = rowColor }, iRow);
        }

        // finally apply date and reformat that cell
        SpreadsheetSetCellValue(objSheet, now(), iRow, 1, 'date');
        SpreadSheetFormatCell(objSheet, { dataformat = 'mm-dd-yyyy', fgcolor = rowColor}, iRow, 1);
    }
</cfscript>
```

*Results:*

[image: Results]

Comment: This still wipes out the background color for rest of the columns except for the date column, but thanks!

Comment: Sure you ran the *exact* code above? Works fine on trycf.com (preserves background color for all columns).

Comment: yes, so basically the difference is my date column is the first one and so I formatted the row on the top, then date column and then rest of the columns. But it kept the fgcolor for date but wiped out for rest of them

Comment: It's not working because you're using slightly different code ;-) In order to work around the bug, the functions have to be called in a very specific order. (1. Create all cells EXCEPT the date 2. Format the row
3. Create and format the date cell) You're doing something different.  Try the *exact* example above. Notice the "date" is the first column and the fgcolor for the other cells is maintained?

Comment: ... and yes, it's silly that one must do it this way, but it's the only way I've found so far to get around the underlying bug.

Comment: yes, unfortunately, I can't, because my client wants a specific order of columns, however, they have agreed to remove the color as date formatting is more important for them :), thanks for all your help!

Comment: @user2675939 - Pretty sure you're misunderstanding the sample code :) **It doesn't change the order of the columns** - only the order in which they're populated and formatted.  *When* that's done doesn't matter. All that matters is *which row/column* you tell `SpreadSheetSetCellValue(...)` to populate. Run the example above, exactly as is, and you'll see the date IS in the first column.